# Apply color from theme attr value to AppCompatTextView programatically

Tags: android, xml, material-design, themes

I am trying to set the text color of an `AppCompatTextView` using the `setColor` method and providing the color from a custom attribute in my theme, but it does not seem to work.

The following is the exact code I am using

```
binding.loginTextTv.setTextColor(R.attr.primaryMainColor)
```

It works fine when I do something like

```
binding.loginTextTv.setTextColor(R.color.primaryColor)
```

How can I change the color from the theme attr?

My custom attr looks like

```
<resources>
  <attr name="primaryMainColor" type="color"/>
</resources>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should pass there not a reference but a color like this: 
`ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.primaryColor)`

or if you want to get a theme color try this:

```kotlin
/**
 * Retrieves colors from theme attributes
 *
 * @throws Resources.NotFoundException Throws NotFoundException if the given ID does not exist.
 * @throws UnsupportedOperationException if the attribute is defined but is
 *         not an integer color or color state list.
 */
@ColorInt
@SuppressLint("Recycle")
fun Context.getThemeColor(@AttrRes colorAttrId: Int): Int {
  return obtainStyledAttributes(intArrayOf(colorAttrId))
    .use { it.getColor(0, Color.WHITE) }
}
```

`drawable.setTint(requireContext().getThemeColor(android.R.attr.colorBackground))`

Or it might be that your custom attribute does not belong to the view (it does not parse it inside when going through attributes)
So the solution for that is to create a derived class from the `AppCompatTextView` and parse your custom attribute on `init()`.

Comment: Awesome this works. I needed to resolve the theme attribute to color before setting it. got it. Thanks.